# Unable to go to url with static asset from https

Tags: javascript, html, assets, service-worker, create-react-app

https://redirect.netlify.com/
The first link works, but not the second. Why?

[image]

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="http://redirect.netlify.com/manifest.json">
        http://redirect.netlify.com/manifest.json
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="https://redirect.netlify.com/manifest.json">
        https://redirect.netlify.com/manifest.json
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Service worker code: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/registerServiceWorker.js

Comment: I don't understand your question. What has the manifest.json to do with SW in your case? Also: the first link, HTTPS version, works for me!

Comment: @pate or if you disable service worker, it'd work too, so I assume the problem is somehow related to service worker?

Comment: @pate turns out you need to visit the root page to get the service worker registered first. Try click on the 2 links on https://redirect.netlify.com/

Comment: the code you added is not the SW code itself, it's the code responsible for registering the SW. Please add the SW code itself. The problem lies in it :-)

Comment: @pate I did provide the link to the SW code https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/registerServiceWorker.js

Comment: No. That is NOT the SW code. That is the code that *registers* the SW. :-)

Comment: @pate right, it's generated by react-scripts during build. Here it is https://pastebin.com/sLJpUwYE